# All TextTypes are NULL Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Why I get null in all the fields of my form?

[image: form]

The buildForm is this:

```
  ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
       'label' => 'Nombre',
       'required' => 'required',
//     'empty_data' => null,
       'empty_data' => '',
       'attr' => array(
           'class' => 'form-name form-control'
        )
        ))
        ->add('surname', TextType::class, array(
             'label' => 'Apellidos',
             'required' => 'required',
             'attr' => array(
                 'class' => 'form-surname form-control'
              )
       ))
```

The result is the same. I tried with and without `empty_data`. How do I delete this `null`?

I am new in Symfony, I start learning.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Have you checked that data is flowing to the form correctly? What happens when you place a `dd()` above the form call with the entity that is feeding the form inside the parentheses of the dd?

Comment: When you say null, do you mean that you are literally getting the word NULL as your screen copy shows? Because that would be just strange unless in your entity you had something like protected name = 'NULL';

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder:

```
           ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nombre',
                'required' => 'required',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-name form-control',
                    'placeholder' => 'place your name',
                )
            ))
```

Comment: I have used it but the result is the same.
What I se it is that when I created the Entities it's all in null.

Comment: That's need to be like that? 
   ` /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $surname = 'NULL';`

Comment: For me no cause it's initialize to a 'NULL' string